How to run Nextjs Backend with NextAuth alongside Keycloak in Local Kubernetes
I have the following services deployed to a Kubernetes cluster running locally on my machine:

Keycloak
NextJS
Ingress-nginx

The NextJS app is basic: it uses NextAuth and the NextAuth Keycloak provider to allow the user to log in and view a protected page.
I have configured Keycloak with a realm and a web client.  This all works fine.
Both services have ingress configurations:

Keycloak is available via auth.starter.local
The NextJS app is available via starter.local

These DNS names are manually configured in my /etc/hosts file to resolve to 127.0.0.1.
When I attempt to log in via the NextJS app (auth.starter.local), I get an error.  This is caused because the backend NextJS app is attempting to retrieve the .well-known config from Keycloak at its DNS name, which it cannot resolve inside the Kubernetes cluster.
How do I get this to work?  Can I configure Kubernetes coredns somehow to get the domain names to resolve from an inside service?

First thing first, the /etc/hosts on your local machine is not shared nor cascaded to the pods/containers inside your Kubernetes clusters. They each has their own /etc/hosts files. To add custom entries to each of those /etc/hosts inside the pod/container, you need to use HostAliases.
You have to map the auth.starter.local custom domain inside the pod/container of your NextJS app to the IP of the service for the Keycloak. Run a kubectl describe on the service to obtain its IP.
Next, add the HostAliases setting to the deployment of your NextJS app (under .spec.template.spec):
hostAliases:
- ip: "x.x.x.x" # replace with the service's cluster IP
  hostnames:
  - "auth.starter.local"

Repeat in reverse if your Keycloak needs to connect to your NextJS app.

Thank @Lukman for this; this "worked" for me and I've marked it as the accepted anser.  The drawback to this approach is that if I make a change to my Keycloak service that causes the service IP to change, then I have to reconfigure the hostAliases with that new IP address.  It seems to me that there should be a DNS-based way to achieve what I'm looking for here using the internal DNS name of the service.

I ended up modifying my coredns configuration to achieve this so that I didn't have to manually enter IP addresses of services into a values.yaml file.  That configuration (original solution described here) is:
        rewrite name auth.starter.local template-keycloak.starter.svc.cluster.local
        rewrite name api.starter.local template-starter-web.starter.svc.cluster.local

These lines create CNAME DNS records in CoreDNS.
To make this change, you'll need to edit the coredns ConfigMap resource.  I used k9s to do this.  I put the lines above just above the kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa { line in the config.  Don't forget to restart the two CoreDNS pods after you make the change.

If you run Keycloak (KC) in Kubernetes (k8s), it is typically exposed through an ingress so that applications outside the cluster can interact with it. For applications inside the cluster, the same configuration is usually required, except when you use network services to avoid an additional hop (e.g., ingress controller) in network traffic.
Keycloak may also be sensitive to the X-Forwarded-Host header, which is used to enable it to work behind proxies (though you can hardcode the hostname FQDN through one of the configuration options). This is useful when configuring different URLs, such as a separate URL for the admin console. Additionally, many companies use split DNS configurations to meet the requirements of the iss claim.
